# What do I do if I need more than 64 if conditions for a calculation formula in Excel 2016

Tags: excel

I have a dropdown list of 104 values in column F. I want if any of the values is selected from that list cloumn, a corresponding value should be referenced from sheet and be inserted the cell in Column i .

If a value is selected in sheet 1 column F then it should match it with a similar value in sheet 2 columnA and also select the value corresponding value in Sheet 2 column B and go back and insert it in sheet 1 Column i.

Please note that each of the 104 values in column F has its corresponding value from a cell address of another worksheet

[image: Asset Dropdown List worksheet][image: The main sheet with conditional statement]

```
=IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A1,'Compensation Rate'!D5,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A2,'Compensation Rate'!C5,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A3,'Compensation Rate'!B5,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A4,'Compensation Rate'!D6,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A5,'Compensation Rate'!C6,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A6,'Compensation Rate'!B6,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A7,'Compensation Rate'!D7,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A8,'Compensation Rate'!C7,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A9,'Compensation Rate'!B7,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A10,'Compensation Rate'!D8,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A11,'Compensation Rate'!C8,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A12,'Compensation Rate'!B8,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A13,'Compensation Rate'!D9,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A14,'Compensation Rate'!C9,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A15,'Compensation Rate'!B9,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A16,'Compensation Rate'!D10,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A17,'Compensation Rate'!C10,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A18,'Compensation Rate'!B10,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A19,'Compensation Rate'!D11,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A20,'Compensation Rate'!C11,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A21,'Compensation Rate'!B11,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A22,'Compensation Rate'!D12,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A23,'Compensation Rate'!C12,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A24,'Compensation Rate'!B12,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A25,'Compensation Rate'!D13,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A26,'Compensation Rate'!C13,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A27,'Compensation Rate'!B13,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A28,'Compensation Rate'!D14,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A29,'Compensation Rate'!C14,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A30,'Compensation Rate'!B14,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A31,'Compensation Rate'!D15,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A32,'Compensation Rate'!C15,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A33,'Compensation Rate'!B15,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A34,'Compensation Rate'!D16,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A35,'Compensation Rate'!C16,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A36,'Compensation Rate'!B16,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A37,'Compensation Rate'!D17,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A38,'Compensation Rate'!C17,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A39,'Compensation Rate'!B17,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A40,'Compensation Rate'!D18,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A41,'Compensation Rate'!C18,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A42,'Compensation Rate'!B18,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A43,'Compensation Rate'!D19,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A44,'Compensation Rate'!C19,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A45,'Compensation Rate'!B19,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A46,'Compensation Rate'!D20,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A47,'Compensation Rate'!C20,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A48,'Compensation Rate'!B20,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A49,'Compensation Rate'!D21,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A50,'Compensation Rate'!C21,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A51,'Compensation Rate'!B21,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A52,'Compensation Rate'!D22,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A53,'Compensation Rate'!C22,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A54,'Compensation Rate'!B22,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A55,'Compensation Rate'!D23,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A56,'Compensation Rate'!C23,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A57,'Compensation Rate'!B23,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A58,'Compensation Rate'!D26,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A59,'Compensation Rate'!C6,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A60,'Compensation Rate'!B26,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A61,'Compensation Rate'!D27,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A62,'Compensation Rate'!C27,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A63,'Compensation Rate'!B27,IF(TRIM(F5)='Asset Dropdown List'!A64,'Compensation Rate'!D28,2))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: I think we will be able to help better if you can [edit] your question to explain what the formula is used for. Please include sample input data and your desired result. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks I have edited the question as suggested.

Comment: As I said above, please include a sample of your input data and desired result. It looks like there's a couple of smaller formulas that could solve this problem for you, but I can't help you if I don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: I have added an image. Regards

Comment: Looks like one for VLOOKUP to me.

Comment: Okay! How do I go about it with  VLOOKUP? Thanks

Comment: What does your worksheet `Asset Dropdown List` look like?

Comment: @PaichengWu It is just a column of with title A and has text values from A1:A104

Comment: Where do you place your `If` formula?

Comment: I am placing the if formulae on column i of Val. Sheet(AGB)

Comment: You can always use and UDF, there is no limits on VBA functions

Comment: I do not see any `$` sign in you `IF` formula.   Could you post the formula in cell `I7` ?

Comment: Step back and explain what you are trying to achieve instead of focusing on a particular function like If(). There is no need to use more than 64 nested IF(), EVER. Your problem is with understanding what Excel can do and proper data architecture.  Use a SMALL data sample, not your whole table and explain the principle of your issue. The we can provide you with new approaches that you can learn and then apply to all your data.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for trying to help,  I’ve edited my question and have updated my question so it’s clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an **IFS function** that can replace multiple, nested IF statements with a single function. So instead of our initial grades example, which has 4 nested IF functions:

> =IF(D2>89,"A",IF(D2>79,"B",IF(D2>69,"C",IF(D2>59,"D","F"))))

It can be made much simpler with a single IFS function:

> =IFS(D2>89,"A",D2>79,"B",D2>69,"C",D2>59,"D",TRUE,"F")

**Source:** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-%E2%80%93-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8

Comment: Does IFS have any No of limit of conditions that it can accept?

Comment: The IFS function allows you to test up to 127 different conditions.

Comment: Then if that is it. It is simply the answer I need. Thanks. I will mark as the correct answer immediately I try and it works.

Comment: @Edwinfad that way you will never learn about better ways to address such a scenario. And there are better ways, if you are only willing to explain your situation and to learn better data architecture.

Comment: @Quiron Pls the IFS () function is giving me a #name? error. Please why is my excel not supportting ifs function?

Comment: I don't have ifs function on my excel because I am not using Office 365. Could you please help out in another way.